# How to avoid dropping levels with 0 frequencies

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two questions (columns `Q1_b` and `Q2_b`) and barplot them next to each other (in the same barplot), the answer options are 1-6. The problem is that noone answered with 4 for `Q1_b`, so the barplot skips to displaying 5 where 4 should be for `Q1_b`, next to the percentage of people who answered 4 for `Q2_b`. How can I make sure R doesn't do this and automatically enters a 0% column if there weren't any answers for a specific option?

```
alldataset<-structure(list(Q1_b = c(6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L), 
                           Q2_b = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L)), 
                      .Names = c("Q1_b", "Q2_b"), 
                      class = "data.frame", 
                      row.names = c(NA, -8L))

Qb<-table(alldataset$Q2_b)
Qf<-table(alldataset$Q1_b)

nrowFUP<-NROW(alldataset$Q1_b)
nrowBL<-NROW(alldataset$Q2_b)

options(digits=6)
newbl <- transform(as.data.frame(table(alldataset$Q2_b)),    
                 percentage_column=Freq/nrowBL*100)

newfup <- transform(as.data.frame(table(alldataset$Q1_b)), 
                    percentage_column=Freq/nrowFUP*100)


matrixQ1<-cbind(newbl$percentage_column, newfup$percentage_column)

matrixQ1dataframe<-data.frame(matrixQ1)
rmatrixQ1<-as.vector(t(matrixQ1dataframe))
roundedrmatrix<-round(rmatrixQ1, digits=0)
barplotmatrix<-matrix(roundedrmatrix)

par(mar=c(7.5,4,3,2), mgp=c(2,.7,0), tck=-.01, las=1, xpd=TRUE)

 b<-barplot(matrix(roundedrmatrix, nr=2), 
           beside=T, xlab="",
           ylab="Percentage",
           cex.lab=0.9, 
           main="Comparison",
           cex.main=0.9, ylim=c(0,70), 
           col=c("black","yellow"), 
           names.arg=c(1:6),
           legend=c("Q2_b","Q1_b"),
           args.legend=list(x="bottomleft", 
                            cex=0.8,
                            inset=c(0.4,-0.4)))
text(x=b, y=roundedrmatrix,labels=roundedrmatrix, pos=3, cex=0.8)
```

R also warns me this will happen by displaying:

```
Warning message:
In cbind(newbl$percentage_column, newfup$percentage_column) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

I have been trying for ages to sort this out but I am not getting anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: I used your data in this form `alldataset <- data.frame(Q1_b=c(26,1,5,3,5,6,6,2), Q2_b=c(1,2,2,5,4,3,6,1))` and it ran without error for me.  Can you `dput(alldataset)` and include the result?

Comment: @MattBagg The result of dput(alldataset) is:
structure(list(Q1_b = c(6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L), Q2_b = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L)), .Names = c("Q1_b", "Q2_b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you never told R that you vectors represent categorical responses with potential values of 1-6, so it does not know to include the 0 counts (you would not want it to include a 0 for 7, 8, 1 million, etc.).

Try replacing your 1st 2 lines with:

```
Qb<-table(factor(alldataset$Q2_b, levels=1:6))
Qf<-table(factor(alldataset$Q1_b, levels=1:6))
```

or run somethingn like:

```
alldataset$Q1_b <- factor(alldataset$Q1_b, levels=1:6)
alldataset$Q2_b <- factor(alldataset$Q2_b, levels=1:6)
```

before the table commands.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `table` to use all values from one to six with `table(factor(x, seq.int(6)))`.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
dat <- t(round(sapply(rev(alldataset),
                      function(x) table(factor(x, seq.int(6)))) / 
                                                         nrow(alldataset) * 100))

par(mar=c(7.5,4,3,2), mgp=c(2,.7,0), tck=-.01, las=1, xpd=TRUE)
b <- barplot(dat, beside=T,xlab="", ylab="Percentage", cex.lab=0.9, 
             main="Comparison", cex.main=0.9, ylim=c(0,70), 
             col=c("black","yellow"), names.arg=c(1:6), legend=names(dat), 
             args.legend=list(x="bottomleft", cex=0.8, inset=c(0.4,-0.4)))
text(x=b, y=dat,labels=dat, pos=3, cex=0.8)
```

[image]